# How can I search for a hashtag and receieve a certain number of recent posts back?

Tags: c#, pagination, instagram

I'm trying to understand the Instagram API.. and all I really want to do is....say i search for #stackoverflow, i'd like to say return 10 results or something... it seems the only one related to what i'm looking for is "/tags/tag-name/media/recent" with a pagination... i messed with pagination but i don't really understand what that meanns?

but then i was reading "On views where pagination is present, we also support the "count" parameter. Simply set this to the number of items you'd like to receive. Note that the default values should be fine for most applications - but if you decide to increase this number there is a maximum value defined on each endpoint."

so there is a way to set a count?  i tried to put "1" and "10" as the parameters but i dont think that worked...

i think this is really simple but i just don't understand it fully, thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply append the `count` to the query string:

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/stackoverflow/media/recent?client_id=CLIENT_ID0&count=10
```

And to get another set of data there is a `next_url` property in the pagination object to call (you append the count there as well)

```
"pagination": {
    "next_max_tag_id": "1386358187743",
    "deprecation_warning": "next_max_id and min_id are deprecated for this endpoint; use min_tag_id and max_tag_id instead",
    "next_max_id": "1386358187743",
    "next_min_id": "1390975436314",
    "min_tag_id": "1390975436314",
    "next_url": "https:\/\/api.instagram.com\/v1\/tags\/stackoverflow\/media\/recent?count=50\u0026client_id=CLIENT_ID\u0026max_tag_id=138833581727630"
}
```

Comment: how do we get max and min ids? in fact how do we get it working in first place?